# Loging a Telnet Session

Tags: logging, telnet

I need to log a telnet session. I tried piping to tee but it broke on a long `ls` with colors.

I just found the flag `-f` (I need the log output within as the the session goes not at the end), but I'm unsure how to apply some control characters (such as backspaces) and remove others to a script log to get a clean string.

Are there other telnet clients with logging? Or some other solution (logging continuously as session goes, clean plain textile without ctrl character for final results for people to look back at what happened, hopefully an easy to install/simple/few dependencies solution)?

Comment: The reason I am asking is I want to write a small telnet wrapper script (aliased to telnet) and read from the log file and several others and combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its due to a bug in tee being unable to handle large amounts of input.
I used a

```
plink -telnet address| tee file
```

instead and that seems to work.